# Create a content type node programmatically

Tags: nodes, 8

I have a content type called **`ip_range`** and i was trying to create a node **programmatically** . I tried the follows :

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;
    $data = array(
      'type' => 'ip_range', 
      'title' => '192.168.7.100/24', 
      'field_ip_range_gw' => '192.168.7.100', 
      'field_ip_range_hidden' => '', 
      'field_ip_range_blocked' => '192.168.7.200', 
      'field_ip_range_access_type' => 'Blocked', 
      'field_ip_threshold' => '20', 
      'field_ip_range_sec_zone' => 'C2', 
      'field_ip_range_vlan_name' => 'Network58', 
      'field_ip_range_vlan_tag' => '4054', 
      'field_ip_range_comment' => 'Ip ranges from 192.168.7.100 to 192.168.7.255', 
    );
    $node = Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->create($data);

    $node->save();
```

But its not creating any . Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

---

Its creating the node . But its creating as **anonymous** user . So i cant see it in front end . That was the problem . How to create it as a admin user ?

Comment: Where did you put this code? In a .module, a .theme?

Comment: this code in drupal root folder and executing this script using drush

Comment: use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;                                                                   $node = Node::create([
 'type' => 'ip_range', 
.
 .   'field_ip_range_comment' => 'Ip ranges from 192.168.7.100 to 192.168.7.255', 
]);
  $node->save();

Comment: Have you tried creating a node afterwards to see if the id has been incremented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Code in **MigrateContentController**:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\migrate_contents\Controller;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

class MigrateContentController extends ControllerBase {

 function migrateContent() {
 $updated = 0;
 $data = array(
   'type' => 'ip_range', 
   'title' => '192.168.7.100/24', 
   'field_ip_range_gw' => '192.168.7.100', 
   'field_ip_range_hidden' => '', 
   'field_ip_range_blocked' => '192.168.7.200', 
   'field_ip_range_access_type' => 'Blocked', 
   'field_ip_threshold' => '20', 
   'field_ip_range_sec_zone' => 'C2', 
   'field_ip_range_vlan_name' => 'Network58', 
   'field_ip_range_vlan_tag' => '4054', 
   'field_ip_range_comment' => 'Ip ranges from 192.168.7.100 to 192.168.7.255', 
 );
 $node = Node::create($data);
 $node->save();
 $updated++;

 return array(
   '#markup' => $updated,
 );
 }
}
```

> Inside your_module.routing.yml

```
migrate_contents.migrate_node:
  path: '/migrate-contents'
    defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\migrate_contents\Controller\MigrateContentController::migrateContent'
    _title: 'Migrate Contents'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

**Note**: Clear the cache before proceeding.

Comment: Not working though ! , and the script has no errors :(

Comment: can you update the question as what you have tried?

Comment: Thanks ,man , actually its creating. But its not listing because am creating the node as anonymous user . DO you know how create it as a admin user ?

Comment: okay , i got it working , don't know why its worked because used **Node::create($data);** instead of  **Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->create($data);** , although am accepting your answer :)